# SQL statements practicing statements answer verification?

Tags: mysql, relational-database, schema

Lets say I have  4  tables

> Region (RegionCode, RegionName)
>
> Customer (CustCode, CustName, CustAdress, CustBalance, RegionCode)
>
> EmployeeType (EmployeeType, HourlyPayRate,)
>
> Employee (EmployeeNo, EmployeeName, EmployeeAddress, RegionCode,
>   EmployeeType)

My goal is to

> List the Employee numbers, names and address of all the employees
>   working in the Region whose code is MUN and the name is John Smith.

My answer is as follows

```
SELECT EmployeeNo, EmploeeName, EmployeeAddress
FROM Employee
WHERE RegionCode = 'MUN' AND EmployeeName = 'John Smith';
```

I am tempted to join tables here, but am I right in saying as I can extract all information from this single table `Employee` I do not have to?

Comment: Your query seems OK to me in regards to the goal.

Comment: @ sticky bit: thanks I am studying for a paper exam so practicing with a pen and paper :)

Comment: I would split the `AND` to a new line and also `EmployeeName = 'John Smith';` I find it makes it easier to remember and understand

Comment: Seems OK. But we have to guess what the base tables mean using table & column names. PS Yes-or-no questions are not very helpful & if you must ask then you should give your reasoning, so we can critique it, otherwise what do we say but "because that's how SQL works" & does our answer, yes or no, tell you that your reasoning is right or wrong? (No.) See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS [Is there any rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097)